# Handle null array indexing error in Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a script that finds all servers in the domain then creates a hash table with the results:

```
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = '(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*)'
$objSearcher.PageSize=1000
[void] $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
[void] $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnshostname")
[void] $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystem")
[void] $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingsystemservicepack")
$objSearcher.FindAll() | %{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Properties.name[0]
        FQDN = $_.Properties.dnshostname[0]
        OS = $_.Properties.operatingsystem[0]
        ServicePack = $_.Properties.operatingsystemservicepack[0]
    }
}
```

I get the "Cannot index into a null array" error when a 2012 R2 server is part of the results because it has no 'operatingsystemservicepack' property:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Nexustek\SHA\Get-DomainServers.ps1:12 char:5
+     New-Object PSObject -Property @{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

How can the script handle the null property and just display it as blank for 2012 R2 servers? I've looked for solutions on Stack Overflow and the Internet in general and found articles about how to test for nulls but nothing that seems to quite match my scenario.

Comment: `ServicePack = if ($_.Properties.operatingsystemservicepack) { $_.Properties.operatingsystemservicepack[0] }`?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!